# Kafka Producer Connection Issue

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, keytab

I am trying send messages through kafka producer but getting following error. I am using following command to establish connection.

`export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=$OSI_HOME/jaas.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=$OSI_HOME/krb5.conf"$OSI_HOME/Custom/confluent/bin/kafka-console-producer --topic testTopic --bootstrap-server <server list> --producer.config producer.properties`

Here's the JAAS config I am using

`KafkaClient { com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useKeyTab=true storeKey=true keyTab="[Location of keytabfile]" serviceName="kafka" useTicketCache=true principal="svc_account@REALM"; };`

I can see producer was able to connect. But when I try to send messages I get following error.

```
[2022-02-23 12:45:56,562] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -7 terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-02-23 12:45:56,563] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker  (id: -7 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-02-23 12:45:56,707] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -13 terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-02-23 12:45:56,707] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker  (id: -13 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-02-23 12:45:56,863] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -12 terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-02-23 12:45:56,863] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker (id: -12 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I tried telnet command for broker list and it's connected so it doesn't seem to be a firewall issue.  I can also do kinit from the server so doesn't seem to be an authentication issue.

Comment: Without knowing how your broker configs are setup or what your JAAS file looks like, I don't think we can answer how you can properly authenticate

Comment: Here's the JAAS config I am using

KafkaClient {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
storeKey=true
keyTab="[Location of keytabfile]"
serviceName="kafka"
useTicketCache=true
principal="svc_account@REALM";
};

Answer (score -1):

git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit-release-tools && (cd gerrit-release-tools && f=`git rev-parse --git-dir`/hooks/commit-msg ; mkdir -p $(dirname $f) ; curl -Lo $f https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/tools/hooks/commit-msg ; chmod +x $f)   enter code here

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).